# Class Loading Leak with Hibernate/Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, resource-leak, classloading

We have Spring/Hibernate-Tests which currently produce a class-loading leak. For technical reasons, the springcontext is initiated per test method. With the initialization of the spring context, a hibernate session is also initizlized.

We could observe that the number of loaded classes is increasing steadily. Upon inspection with JProfiler, we found out, that any instantiation of the hibernate session triggers a load on all entity-class objects. As we have three digit number of hibernate entities, this leads to a massive bloat in metaspace and compressed class space.

The question is: Why is the same class loader loading the same classes again and again and does not realize, that the class-objects are already loaded?

**Edit: Clarification of the scenario**

This issue occured as part of a software modernization-project, where functions from a legacy app are ported into a spring managed part of the application. During production this works fine - the applicationserver initializes the spring context (and therefore hibernate), the legacy core accesses this via some static acessors.

In testing stage we have to integrate the legacy testing framework with the spring core. For technical reasons (the old testing framework is somewhat quirky) we have to re-establish the spring-context per test, not per test class. As there is quite a number of tests in the testset, this eventually leads to a OOME within the compressed class space.

As the tests actually make use of the database connection, each test initializes a hibernate session. We are using Spring 5.2.13 and Hibernate 5.4.29.

Comment: Because they are proxied. But the question is why is a hibernate session initialized? Also initializing this per test method is quite slow, I would strongly suggest to look for a better method. I also hope you aren't doing this yourself but relying on the Spring Test Context framework here.

Comment: Its rather complex and part of a long running software modernization project. My question: I have an `AEntity`. Why do I see `AEntity.class` being loaded twice in the class loader? I am aware, there might be proxies around, but this is not, what JProfiler reported.

Comment: Now if I would know the why I would have told you. But as mentioned why is there even a session initialized when your application context starts? (Or did you  mean `SessionFactory` and not `Session`)?

Comment: I have tried to clarify the scenario

Comment: And still haven't answered the questions I had. Why is there a Hibernate `Session` initialized as part of the context and are you creating contexts yourself or using the Spring Test Context framework. Also knowing which Spring version you are on is also good to know as well as the Hibernate version. j

Comment: Added the information. I thought, it would be obvious, that the tests actually use the database.

Comment: That the tests use a database is obvious but in your description you state that starting the context also initializes a session, which is weird as that shouldn't happen. But still you haven't answered **how are you creating a context, yourself, or using the Spring Test Context Framework**. Please add some code (and please don't dumb it down as that probably doesn't show the issue).

Comment: A class can not be loaded multiple times from the same class loader. So the only way this can happen is, when you have multiple class loaders. I don't know your setup, but it seems that your test framework might be messing with class loaders which could be the cause for this.